# Error creating a system.io.stream for ms graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to update a OneNote page in C# using MS Graph per the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp.

```
var Stream = new List<Stream>()
    {
        new Stream
        {
            Target = "#para-id",
            Action = "insert",
            Position = "before",
            Content = "<img src=\"image-url-or-part-name\" alt=\"image-alt-text\" />"
        },
        new Stream
        {
            Target = "#list-id",
            Action = "append",
            Content = "<li>new-page-content</li>"
        }
    };
```

But keep getting the error:

> "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'Stream'"

I can't figure out any way to create a stream that the Onenotepage object will accept.

I've tried variations of

```
    IRandomAccessStream stream = null;
    Stream content = onRichText.Document.SaveToStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, stream);
```

but get the error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

Answer (score 0):

It appears the provided C# example is *invalid* since [Update OneNote page content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) endpoint accepts *an array of [`patchContentCommand` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/patchcontentcommand?view=graph-rest-1.0)* as a request body.

The request

```
PATCH /me/onenote/pages/{id}/content
[
    {
       "action":"append",
       "target":"div:{72e378de-be4b-4633-86bc-8e136f9b3c2e}{107}",
       "content":"<h1>Some content goes here...</h1>",
       "position":"before"
    }
]
```

could be constructed via [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) like this:

```
var patchCommands = new List<OnenotePatchContentCommand>();
patchCommands.Add(new OnenotePatchContentCommand()
   {
        Target = "div:{72e378de-be4b-4633-86bc-8e136f9b3c2e}{107}",
        Action = OnenotePatchActionType.Append,
        Position = OnenotePatchInsertPosition.Before,
        Content = "<h1>Some content goes here...</h1>"
   });

var request = graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages[pageId].Content.Request();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), request.RequestUrl);
message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchCommands), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
```

> Note: has been verified against [`Microsoft.Graph 1.16.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/)